# Tricky T/F... convergence

Tags: real-analysis

T or F?

1) If $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, then the sequence {$1/n$} is unbounded.

Also similarly...

2) If {$x_n$} is unbounded and $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, then $1/x_n \rightarrow 0$.

For the first one, I would say that is true because the limit of  {$1/n$}  would approach infinity, thus making it unbounded?

And the second one, also seems true by similar logic. Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: $1,1,2,1,3,1,4,\ldots$.

Comment: hmmm is this for #2?...would this limit not approach infinity?

Comment: i guess not actually. I don't think a limit could be defined in this case? i'm not too sure

Comment: Yes, it's for 2). The limit of $(1/x_n)$ here does not exist (and in particular, is not $0$).

Comment: Also, note for 1), the sequence $(1/x_n)$ would be unbounded, but it might not converge to $\infty$ (the sequence $(1/|x_n|)$ would converge to $\infty$).

Comment: Great...just to clarify no limit exists for the sequence you gave as well, correct?

Comment: oh right ok, I often get confused between being bounded and convergence to infinity

Comment: Yes, that's right; but the sequence $(x_n)$ from my first comment  is, of course, unbounded.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. If you put up a formal answer, I'll accept it if you'd like. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is true; but note the sequence $(1/x_n)$ need not converge to $\infty$. The sequence $(1/|x_n|)$, however, would.  Consider here, for example, the sequence $(1/2,-1/3,1/4,-1/5,\ldots)$.

For the second one, consider the sequence $(1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,\ldots)$. Note this sequence is unbounded, but the sequence of reciprocals does not converge to $0$.

(If you knew $(x_n)$ converged to $\infty$ (or to $-\infty$), then you could conclude  the sequence of reciprocals would converge to $0$.)